# Amazon EC2 IIS new site displaying IIS home page instead of custom site

Tags: iis, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying out an Amazon EC2 Windows 2012 R2 instance. I have tried the following steps:

1. Installed IIS server in EC2 instance
2. Allow HTTP 80 port for this instance
3. Add DNS record for prayaslearning.com on my hosting provider to Amazon EC2's public IP.
4. add site in IIS server; add assigned custom folder to it

But whenever I tried to browse http://prayaslearning.com/ it shows the IIS home page instead of my custom home page. What additional settings do I need to do?

**EDIT**
in amazon EC2 it says i have Public IP as 52.76.49.242 
and private IP as 172.31.22.122

in IIS for binding it only display 172.31.22.122

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your site codes are on a different home Directory then the default IIS, you need to set that for your domain.

This link shows the steps in detail: http://www.serverintellect.com/support/iis/alt-home-dir/

Comment: i need both default website and my site should run simultaneously

Comment: Then you must have virtualhosting on IIS explained in this KB: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/190008

Answer (score 0):

The part you are missing is you need to BIND the incoming host name to the correct website - you do this in IIS manager.

Right click the site in IIS, select Edit BIndings and put in your host name.

Comment: it works only mistake was i added www.prayaslearning.com instead of only prayaslearning.com

Comment: You can add both if you want www and non-www to the bindings.

Comment: but by now www redirecting default website not on desired website

Comment: @ddw147 you can apply a redirect from domain to www.domain or vice-versa  [ http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2011/08/iis-7-redirect-domaincom-to.html ]